# find explorer.exe hwnd

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

I want to find & enumerate explorer.exe.

Found 'EnumChildWindows' API call but how to 'get' explorer.exe hwnd ???

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

In your enum callback procedure, you can call GetClassName and look for top level hWNDs with the approprate classname for Explorer (ExploreWClass I think - can find with Spy++).

I think you want EnumWindows to enum the top level windows, not EnumChildWindows.

Comment: true! yes 'ExploreWClass' you are right! I enumerate the child
but I suppose can list the explorer 'folder windows' it cant..

thnx for quick answer

--

make a loop :

vb.net :
do
hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, 0, "CabinetWClass", Nothing)
loop until hwnd=0

lists all forlder windows!